# Why does $\|\sum_{i=1}^{N}\langle f,\phi_i\rangle\phi_i\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}|\langle f,\phi_i\rangle|^2 $?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm reading about Fourier analysis and there is one equality, which I don't understand. Why does:

$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{N}\langle f,\phi_i\rangle\phi_i\right\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}|\langle f,\phi_i\rangle|^2  ,$$

where $f$ and $\phi_i$s are infinite dimensional complex-valued "vectors". In my book they are functions, but they are thought of as infinite dimensional vectors. The $\phi_i$s are mutually orthonormal.

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^b f(x)\overline{g(x)}\;dx$$
$$\|f\| = \sqrt{\int_a^b |f(x)|^2\;dx}$$

I guess I'm supposed to use the Pythagorean theorem here?:

if vectors $\boldsymbol{a}_1$, ..., $\boldsymbol{a}_n$ are mutually orthogonal then

$$\|\boldsymbol{a}_1+ \cdots+\boldsymbol{a}_n\|^2 = \|\boldsymbol{a}_1\|^2+\cdots+\|\boldsymbol{a}_n\|^2$$

Thank you for any help! Please let me know if you need more information :)

Comment: you basically answered your own question. Just notice what $a_i$ is in your case, and then note that $\|a_i\|=|\langle f,\varphi_i \rangle|$.

Comment: Probably called Plancherel or Parseval's Theorem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More explicitly:

$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^N\langle f,\phi_i\rangle\phi_i\right\|^2=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^N\langle f,\phi_i\rangle\phi_i\,,\,\sum_{i=1}^N\langle f,\phi_i\rangle\phi_i\right\rangle=$$

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^N\langle f,\phi_i\rangle\overline{\langle f,\phi_j\rangle}\langle\phi_i\,,\,\phi_j\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^N|\langle f\,,\,\phi_i\rangle|^2$$

since

$$\langle\phi_i\,,\,\phi_j\rangle=\delta_{i,j}=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;i=j\\{}\\0&,\;\;i\neq j\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: $|\cdots|^2=\langle\cdots,\cdots\rangle$. Expand. The crossed terms vanish by orthogonality.

Comment: OP noted as much himself.

Comment: Yes he did, @JonathanY., yet he didn't answer his own question...

Comment: @DonAntonio just so. That's why I feel helping OP nail down the specifics is probably more helpful than reiterating the basic concept he indicated he understood. What's more, I suspect you agree (by your answer above).

Comment: The essential word: "expand".

Comment: @JonathanY., the passing from the "understanding" to the "actually do it" can be a little tricky because of that sigma. And yes, taking this into account, I basically agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n \langle f,\varphi_i\rangle\varphi_i\right\|^2 &=
\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n \langle f,\varphi_i\rangle\varphi_i,\sum_{i=1}^n \langle f,\varphi_i\rangle\varphi_i\right\rangle
=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \big\langle\langle f,\varphi_i\rangle\varphi_i,\langle f,\varphi_j\rangle\varphi_j \big\rangle \\ &=
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \langle f,\varphi_i\rangle\overline{\langle f,\varphi_j\rangle}\langle\varphi_i,\varphi_j\rangle=
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \langle f,\varphi_i\rangle\overline{\langle f,\varphi_j\rangle}\delta_{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^n |\langle f,\varphi_i\rangle|^2
\end{align}

Comment: I wonder how is this answer different from mine and what does it add to the understanding of the solution...

Comment: Writing TeX is slow...

Comment: *That* slow, @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla ? Well, perhaps yes...

Comment: And web browsers are treacherous.

Comment: It took me for ever to write my answer. I didn't know what I was writing with the extremely slow MathJax. I agrre, that the two answers are almost identical.